# How to optimize WordPress site built with Revolution Slider, Elementor and How to improve PageSpeed Score?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, pagespeed, revolution-slider, elementor

My boss just bought a theme yesterday on ThemeForest, when I logged in I found out that the theme was built with Elementor and Revolution Slider. Then I checked PageSpeed and the score was **REALLY low** ( 7 on mobile and 27 on desktop ). 
So now I really don't know what to do to optimize the site and improve the PageSpeed score, is there any way I can do with this issue?

Comment: minify js and css and if possible use cache plugin in wordpress

Comment: image optimize, CDN , Cookie free domain also part of speed optimize

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com check you site speed here, And also follow the instructions

Comment: I think its better to google it first instead of here.

Comment: I did google it, but tbh all I found was just a bunch of posts about how to optimize a site in general, but my issue is just about revolution sliders and elementor. But thank you guys so much.